# ROS2 runtime launch of nodes

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I have a need to run ROS nodes from other ROS nodes at runtime. [Composition](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Composition/) look like that I need. But it using C++ and rclcpp. My nodes are written in Python. Does ROS2 have ways to run nodes at runtime from other nodes for python?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339444/ros2-runtime-launch-of-nodes/) by [georgy](https://answers.ros.org/users/50112/georgy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Managed and life-cycle nodes are currently not supported in Python, as far as I know. See also #q328772 -- I don't believe the situation has changed.

The [Features Status](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Features/) page seems to confirm this:

> Composition of node components at compile-, link- or dlopen-time: Currently only in C++.

It might be possible to load ROS 2 Python nodes at runtime using some Python 'tricks', but it would not seem to be officially supported at this point.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [georgy](https://answers.ros.org/users/50112/georgy/) on 2019-12-08**:
Thanks!
I will look for other ways. I think your answer is a solution in my situation.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-08**:
We could wait for other board members to respond.

They may know of a way I'm not aware of.